# Is there any practical difference between "calories" and "calories from fat"?

Tags: diet, weight-loss, calories

I was eating a frozen yogurt earlier and noticed the nutrition label said:

```
Calories 200
Fat Cal. 70
```

I'm not sure what to make of this. I'm guessing 200 is the total calories, 70 of which comes from fat. I'm currently watching my diet trying not to take more than 2000 calories per day. Does it matter where the calories I'm in taking comes from?

I know it matters from a nutrition perspective but I mean does it matter from a weight loss perspective?

If fat calories are important is that because they are harder to burn than regular calories?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to relate it to some of your fitness goals, or training regimen? As it is, it is a straight nutrition question, which isn't allowed, and it will likely be closed as off topic. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and popular) answer is 'No', a calorie is a calorie and once converted to ATP it works the same way.

The correct and longest answer is: 'it is not that simple'. In fact, it the shortest answer would fill a whole book [Why We Get Fat: And What to Do About It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307272702)

If you really don't want to read a book (I recommend you do) search for 'Paleo Diet' and follow the advice.

Comment: ordered the book as it has a lot of good reviews.